# As a private citizen working with people with disabilities, how can I request a hearing for HR1120?

Tags: united-states, congress

I recently heard about this proposed and sponsored bill earlier this morning when I was getting additional information for a deaf-blind adult. I, being a one of a few number of people who are passionate in working with deaf-blind children and adults, I think that this bill needs to support the entire population of people, both children and adults, who are blind, deaf, or deaf-blind.
So, how can I request a hearing at the state capitol so I and my friends can testify if this is a federal bill?

Comment: There is a mix of question and advocacy here. Remember you don't need to convince us. You can improve your question by removing the middle section "part of the reason....who are blind, deaf, or deaf-blind" Here is the [edit] link

Comment: What do you mean by a "hearing"?  Do you want the federal bill to be proposed in the state legislature?  Or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of having a "hearing" is called "lobbying".

You can call your Congress member's district office to arrange a meeting. You'll probably be asked to fill out some paperwork to prepare for the meeting. It may be rather complex, so if you can form an interest group you can share the load.

You then go to see your Congressperson at the arranged time, usually in their local office (not the national or state Capitol), and explain what you are asking and make your case.

There are various resources explaining the lobbying process on the internet. I used one produced by the Quakers: [How to meet with Congress](https://www.fcnl.org/updates/how-to-meet-with-congress-19)

Comment: Ah, lobbying is a term I'm well-acquainted with. I just didn't realise that's what it meant. Could I use the  court case I purchased from Washington County to further press my points? https://www.kafourymcdougal.com/case-studies/washington-county-jury-awards-nearly-1-million-whistleblower/

Comment: How you argue your case is entirely up to you.